# AddDays() in for loop

Tags: c#, datetime, for-loop

I want to use AddDays() method in for loop. But it doesn't work. in spite of using in loop, day value is not increasing. Then it is transforming infinite loop. For example;

```
DateTime exDt = tempPermissionWarning[i].planned_start_date;
for (DateTime dt = exDt; dt <= newTo; dt.AddDays(1))
{
    context = context + dt.ToShortDateString() + "æ" + tempPermissionWarning[i].resource_name) + ¨";
}
```

How I use AddDays() method in a for loop

Thank you so much

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`dt.AddDays(1)` returns a new object, which you are discarding.

You could use `dt = dt.AddDays(1)` in the `for` loop, in place of what you currently have.

Answer (score 4):

The `AddDays` methods returns a new `DateTime`, so your `dt` object never gets modified. You can reassign it however. This should work:

```
for (DateTime dt = exDt; dt <= newTo; dt = dt.AddDays(1)) { ... }
```